# Mercurial - How to merge two heads where many files were deleted in one?

Tags: merge, mercurial

I am using a machine that has two heads: default and test. Test was a branch created from default some time ago. A while ago, thousands of files were deleted from test. There were also many changes to files on test. All these deleted or changed files on test are also on default. I want to merge the two heads such that all the files that have been changed on test stay changed but all the files that were deleted and are still on default are added.

When I merge, it makes me one by one decide whether to keep the deleted files:
local changed a/b.txt which remote deleted
use (c)hanged version or (d)elete?

I don't mind manually merging the files with differences but I don't want to press c thousands of times for the deleted files...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your situation, you *may* be able to use the `:local` (or `:other`) merge tool here.

Note that this resolves conflicted files strictly in favor of one or other other parent (p1 or p2), and is therefore very different from `:merge-local` or `:merge-other`.  That is, if you are on branch `default` and are merging branch `test`, and file `both.txt` is modified in both branches (with respect to the merge base version), then:

```
hg merge --tool :local
```

will discard the `both.txt` changes in `test` entirely, taking only the `both.txt` changes from `default`.  (If another file `test.txt` is modified only in `test`, Mercurial will take those changes.)

---

If all else fails, though, you can simulate entering `c` to every prompt using the following trick on a Unix-like system (I have no idea if it works on Windows):

```
yes c | hg --config ui.interactive=true merge test
```

Normally, if the input to `hg` is coming from a pipe (as in this case: `yes c` prints an infinite sequence of lines consisting of just `c`), it does not try to read from its standard input (so it would act as though you typed `u` to every prompt).  However, setting `ui.interactive` to `true` forces Mercurial to read from stdin anyway.

You can combine this with `--tool :merge-local` or `--tool :merge-other`, if you like.

Comment: This sounds very close to what I'm looking for. I guess I want a mix of :local and :other... I am hoping to basically use local for all the actual conflicts and other for all the deletions.

For example when I do hg update test I get 83 files updated, 0 files merged, 3645 files removed, 0 files unresolved. So if I am hoping to have the 3645 files kept on default while the 83 updated files will be using the version from test. Is there a way to combine :local and :other to achieve this end?

Comment: @Mr.Kaplan: unfortunately, no, there is not—at least, not without writing some Python code. It's not hard to inject new Python code into Mercurial through the extensions interface, and it should be reasonably straightforward to inject a special-purpose merge, but I have not actually done it.